# Batch call different HTAs

Tags: batch-file, hta

Is there a way to call multiple HTA-APPs in one batch?

I have several pages of HTA that I want to call in different places from a batch.

For example:

```
<!-- :: Batch section

@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=|" %%a in ('mshta.exe "%~F0"') do (
    set "field1=%%a"
    set "field2=%%b"
)

echo %field1%
echo %field2%

set var=hallo
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('mshta.exe "%~F0" %var%') do set "HtaResult=%%a"

echo Result = %HtaResult%

echo End of HTA window
pause
goto :EOF
```

The problem is that I want to call both HTAs in a batch.
At the moment, I always call only the first HTA. Is there a possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the schema of your previous question

```
<!-- :: Batch section
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem use command line arguments to tell the hta what to do

    rem Defined which tokens we need and the delimiter between them
    for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=|" %%a in ('mshta.exe "%~F0" test1') do (
        set "field1=%%a"
        set "field2=%%b"
    )
    echo End of HTA 1 window, reply: "%field1%" "%field2%"

    for /F "tokens=1" %%a in ('mshta.exe "%~F0" test2') do (
        set "field1=%%a"
    )
    echo End of HTA 2 window, reply: "%field1%"

    pause
    goto :EOF
-->

<HTML>
<HEAD>

<!-- you will need to give an ID to the HTA -->

<HTA:APPLICATION SCROLL="no" SYSMENU="no" ID="thisHTAID" >

<TITLE>HTA Buttons</TITLE>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
    window.resizeTo(374,400);

    // function handling test1 hta output
    function myFunction() {
        new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            .GetStandardStream(1)
            .WriteLine(
                [ // Array of elements to return joined with the delimiter
                      document.getElementById("myText").value
                    , document.getElementById("myText2").value
                ].join('|')
            );
        window.close();
    };

    // functio handling test2 hta output
    function myButton( selected ){
        new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            .GetStandardStream(1)
            .WriteLine( selected );
        window.close()
    };

    // on window load select what div to show depending on command line 
    window.onload = function(){
        var commandLine = thisHTAID.commandLine;
        commandLine = commandLine.substr( 
            self.location.pathname.length 
            + ( commandLine.substr(0,1) === '"' ? 2 : 0 )
        ).replace(/^\s+/g,'');
        document.getElementById( commandLine ).style.display='block';
    };

</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

    <!-- hide hta screens inside div tags -->

    <div id="test1" style='display:none'>
        <h3>A demonstration of how to access a Text Field</h3>
        <input type="text" id="myText"  value="0123">
        <input type="text" id="myText2" value="4567">
        <p>Click the "Login" button to get the text in the text field.</p>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Login</button>
    </div>

    <div id="test2" style='display:none'>
        <h3>Just another demostration</h3>
            <button onclick="myButton(1)">button1</button>
            <button onclick="myButton(2)">button2</button>
    </div>


</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The basic idea exposed in code comments is to determine what layer to show depending on command line arguments given when calling the HTA

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think so that I can solve my problem!
I do not quite understand the part with the "window.onload = function (), can you explain it to me more exactly?
How can I adjust this when I 3 ads have?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: And what would this part look like if I wanted to pass several variables from the FOR loop to JScript? Thanks

Comment: @TheDude, you should not make changes to the elements in the page until it has ended the load process so the code to show the appropriate layer is executed when the load event is fired. Look at how the layer is passed from the FOR command into the commandLine property and change it to parse more arguments